# Trying to return objects similar to mapping

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch, use-effect

I'm trying to return a list of objects to later display in ag-grid. however i was initially trying to map but noticed its not an array, it is only enclosed in {} and therefore was getting the not a function error. Any tips would be extremely appreciated or links to relevant resources as i havent been able to find anything that helps me

the api returns {"author": "j.k rowling", "title": "Harry Potter", "id":"1", "pages":"1000"}

```
  useEffect(() => {
        fetch(http://fakeapi.com/)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => json.map(res => {
                return {
                    author: res.author,
                    title: res.title,
                    id: res.id,
                    pages: res.pages,
                };
            })
            ).then(res => setRowData(res));
    }, []);
```

Comment: You can try `Object.values(json).map`

Comment: been trying this but no luck

Answer (score 0):

The response you are getting from your server shows that you are not getting an array but instead 1 artist. You need to make your server return an array of books info. So your JSON response would be:

```
[
    {
      "id":"1",
      "author": "j.k rowling",
      "title": "Harry Potter",
      "pages":"7000"
    },
    {
      "id":"2",
      "author": "a.k sayomh",
      "title": "Singer role",
      "pages":"10000"
    },
    //...
]
```

Then in your ag-grid you can then use the `.map` function like you were doing.

If you don't get an array of books info then that API is not meant for your use case.

Let's say the API return an object if the total amount of data is 1 and an array if more. Then what you could do it.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(http://fakeapi.com/)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => Array.isArray(json)
        ? json.map(res => ({
            author: res.author,
            title: res.title,
            id: res.id,
            pages: res.pages,
          ))
        : [json]
      ).then(res => setRowData(res));
}, []);
```

Comment: yeah i understand that im not receiving an array. i can't alter the server so have to work with the objects inside {//...} and know that means i can't just map it but its the code to do that i do not know

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to get an array of books? if yes are you sure you are sending the right request?